# *SOLVED* Error when trying to create the microros firmware with generate_lib as RTOS

Tags: ros

I'm currently trying to make a custom message for a micro-ROS - Teensy communicaton. I found [this tutorial](https://micro.ros.org/docs/tutorials/advanced/create_new_type/) on how to include custom ROS messages in micro-ROS. The first thing this tutorial says I should do is to go to "firmware/mcu_ws". So I tried to make this folder with the `ros2 run micro_ros_setup create_firmware_ws.sh generate_lib` command, but I always got this output.
I already tried reinstalling micro-ROS, reinstalling python3 and reinstalling the python3-catking-pkg, but nothing worked.

I'd really appreciate any help I can get.

````
(I had to remove the first 40 lines or so, because of the maximum character length, but they were also just cloning processes)
=== ./ros2/rosidl_defaults (git) ===                             
Cloning into '.'...                                              
=== ./ros2/test_interface_files (git) ===                        
Cloning into '.'...                                              
=== ./ros2/unique_identifier_msgs (git) ===                                                                                        
Cloning into '.'...                                              
...........                                                      
=== ./eProsima/Micro-CDR (git) ===                               
Cloning into '.'...                                              
=== ./eProsima/Micro-XRCE-DDS-Client (git) ===                                                                                     
Cloning into '.'...                                              
=== ./uros/micro_ros_msgs (git) ===                              
Cloning into '.'...                                              
=== ./uros/micro_ros_utilities (git) ===                         
Cloning into '.'...                                              
=== ./uros/rcl (git) ===                                         
Cloning into '.'...                                              
=== ./uros/rclc (git) ===                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
Cloning into '.'...                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
=== ./uros/rcutils (git) ===                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
Cloning into '.'...                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
=== ./uros/rmw_microxrcedds (git) ===                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
Cloning into '.'...                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
=== ./uros/rosidl_typesupport (git) ===                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
Cloning into '.'...                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
=== ./uros/rosidl_typesupport_microxrcedds (git) ===                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
Cloning into '.'...                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
=== ./uros/tracetools (git) ===                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
Cloning into '.'...                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
Crosscompiled environment: cleaning path                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
[0.683s] WARNING:colcon.colcon_ros.prefix_path.catkin:The path '/home/fabi/projects/install/example_interfaces' in the environment variable CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH doesn't exist                                                                                           
[0.683s] WARNING:colcon.colcon_ros.prefix_path.catkin:The path '/home/fabi/projects/install/microxrcedds_client' in the environment variable CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH doesn't exist                                                                                          
[0.684s] WARNING:colcon.colcon_ros.prefix_path.catkin:The path '/home/fabi/projects/install/microcdr' in the environment variable CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH doesn't exist                                                                                                     
[0.684s] WARNING:colcon.colcon_ros.prefix_path.catkin:The path '/home/fabi/projects/install/micro_ros_agent' in the environment variable CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH doesn't exist                                                                                              
[0.684s] WARNING:colcon.colcon_ros.prefix_path.catkin:The path '/home/fabi/projects/install/CarCom' in the environment variable CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH doesn't exist                                                                                                       
[0.684s] WARNING:colcon.colcon_ros.prefix_path.catkin:The path '/home/fabi/projects/install/MXObjects' in the environment variable CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH doesn't exist                                                                                                    
[0.684s] WARNING:colcon.colcon_ros.prefix_path.catkin:The path '/home/fabi/projects/install/MXJoystick' in the environment variable CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH doesn't exist                                                                                                   
[0.684s] WARNING:colcon.colcon_ros.prefix_path.catkin:The path '/home/fabi/projects/microros_ws/install/microxrcedds_client' in the environment variable CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH doesn't exist                                                                              
[0.684s] WARNING:colcon.colcon_ros.prefix_path.catkin:The path '/home/fabi/projects/microros_ws/install/microcdr' in the environment variable CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH doesn't exist                                                                                         
Starting >>> ament_package                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
Starting >>> ament_lint                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
Starting >>> gtest_vendor                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
Starting >>> ament_cppcheck                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
Starting >>> ament_pycodestyle                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
Finished <<< gtest_vendor [1.83s]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
Starting >>> gmock_vendor                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
Finished <<< gmock_vendor [0.24s]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
--- stderr: ament_package                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
Traceback (most recent call last):                               
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/colcon_core/executor/__init__.py", line 91, in __call__                                                                                                                                                                        
    rc = await self.task(*args, **kwargs)                                                                                          
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/colcon_core/task/__init__.py", line 93, in __call__                                                                                                                                                                            
    return await task_method(*args, **kwargs)                                                                                      
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/colcon_ros/task/ament_python/build.py", line 105, in build                                                                                                                                                                     
    return await extension.build(additional_hooks=additional_hooks)                                                                
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/colcon_core/task/python/build.py", line 59, in build                                                                                                                                                                           
    available_commands = await self._get_available_commands(                                                                       
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/colcon_core/task/python/build.py", line 142, in _get_available_commands                                                                                                                                                        
    output = await check_output(                                 
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/colcon_core/subprocess.py", line 128, in check_output                                                                                                                                                                          
    assert not rc, f'Expected {args} to pass: {stderr_data}'                                                                       
AssertionError: Expected ['/usr/bin/python3', 'setup.py', '--help-commands'] to pass: Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                                                              
  File "setup.py", line 6, in <module>                           
    setup(                                                       
  File "/home/fabi/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 87, in setup                                                                                                                                                                      
    return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)                         
  File "/home/fabi/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/core.py", line 164, in setup                                                                                                                                                              
    ok = dist.parse_command_line()                               
  File "/home/fabi/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 471, in parse_command_line                                                                                                                                                 
    if self.handle_display_options(option_order):                                                                                  
  File "/home/fabi/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 1185, in handle_display_options                                                                                                                                                       
    return _Distribution.handle_display_options(self, option_order)                                                                
  File "/home/fabi/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 685, in handle_display_options                                                                                                                                             
    self.print_commands()                                        
  File "/home/fabi/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 962, in print_commands                                                                                                                                                                
    cmdclass = ep.load()                                         
  File "/home/fabi/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/_vendor/importlib_metadata/__init__.py", line 194, in load 
  module = import_module(match.group('module'))                                                                                  
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module                                                      
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)                                                                    
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import                                                                  
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load                                                                
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked                                                       
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked                                                                
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 848, in exec_module                                                          
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed                                                     
  File "/home/fabi/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sphinx/setup_command.py", line 20, in <module>                                                                                                                                                                  
    from sphinx.application import Sphinx                                                                                          
  File "/home/fabi/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sphinx/application.py", line 43, in <module>                                                                                                                                                                    
    from sphinx.registry import SphinxComponentRegistry                                                                            
  File "/home/fabi/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sphinx/registry.py", line 24, in <module>                                                                                                                                                                       
    from sphinx.builders import Builder                          
  File "/home/fabi/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sphinx/builders/__init__.py", line 26, in <module>                                                                                                                                                              
    from sphinx.util import import_object, logging, progress_message, rst, status_iterator                                                                                                                                                                            
  File "/home/fabi/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sphinx/util/rst.py", line 21, in <module>                                                                                                                                                                       
    from jinja2 import Environment, environmentfilter                                                                              
ImportError: cannot import name 'environmentfilter' from 'jinja2' (/home/fabi/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jinja2/__init__.py)                                                                                                                                  
---                                                              
Failed   <<< ament_package [2.52s, exited with code 1]                                                                             
Aborted  <<< ament_pycodestyle [2.46s]                           
Aborted  <<< ament_lint [2.52s]                                  
Aborted  <<< ament_cppcheck [2.51s]                              

Summary: 2 packages finished [2.99s]                             
  1 package failed: ament_package                                
  3 packages aborted: ament_cppcheck ament_lint ament_pycodestyle                                                                  
  1 package had stderr output: ament_package                                                                                       
  54 packages not processed                                      
Expected ['/usr/bin/python3', 'setup.py', '--help-commands'] to pass: Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                                                                              
  File "setup.py", line 6, in <module>                           
    setup(                                                       
  File "/home/fabi/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 87, in setup                                                                                                                                                                      
    return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)                         
  File "/home/fabi/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/core.py", line 164, in setup                                                                                                                                                              
    ok = dist.parse_command_line()                               
  File "/home/fabi/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 471, in parse_command_line                                                                                                                                                 
    if self.handle_display_options(option_order):                                                                                  
  File "/home/fabi/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 1185, in handle_display_options                                                                                                                                                       
    return _Distribution.handle_display_options(self, option_order)                                                                
  File "/home/fabi/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 685, in handle_display_options                                                                                                                                             
    self.print_commands()                                        
  File "/home/fabi/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 962, in print_commands                                                                                                                                                                
    cmdclass = ep.load()                                         
  File "/home/fabi/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/_vendor/importlib_metadata/__init__.py", line 194, in load                                                                                                                                           
    module = import_module(match.group('module'))                                                                                  
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module                                                      
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)                                                                    
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import                                                                  
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load                                                                
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked                                                       
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked                                                                
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 848, in exec_module                                                          
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed                                                     
  File "/home/fabi/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sphinx/setup_command.py", line 20, in <module>                                                                                                                                                                  
    from sphinx.application import Sphinx                                                                                          
  File "/home/fabi/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sphinx/application.py", line 43, in <module>
   from sphinx.registry import SphinxComponentRegistry
  File "/home/fabi/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sphinx/registry.py", line 24, in <module>
    from sphinx.builders import Builder
  File "/home/fabi/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sphinx/builders/__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    from sphinx.util import import_object, logging, progress_message, rst, status_iterator
  File "/home/fabi/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sphinx/util/rst.py", line 21, in <module>
    from jinja2 import Environment, environmentfilter
ImportError: cannot import name 'environmentfilter' from 'jinja2' (/home/fabi/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jinja2/__init__.py)```
````

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the solution.
I solved it by removing the jinja2 version I had installed and installing an older version (3.0).